# JavaFX update TextArea from another thread using Platform.runLater

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to update TextArea using `Platform.runLater` from another class that implements `Runnable`.
I have all my GUI in a class (there is where my TextArea is), i'm creating a `new server` thread and running it when i create the gui. Im trying to use `Platform.runLater` from the `Server` thread to update my `TextArea` but `Platform.runLater` cant reach my TextArea.

```
public class SimulationWindow {
    public SimulationWindow instance() {
        return this;
    }
    public static void DisplaySimulationWindow() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Stage SimuStage = new Stage();
        SimuStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        SimuStage.setTitle("Simulation Window");
        Server myServer = new Server(instance());
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(myServer);
        serverThread.start();
        TextArea serverTextArea;
         .
         .
         .
}

public class Server implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            whileConnected();
        .
        .
    }
    private void whileConnected() throws IOException {

        sendMessage(message);

        do {
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();  
                showMessage(message);
                .
                .
                .
    }
   private void showMessage(String x) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> serverTextArea.appendText(x));          
   }
```

I tried passing the instance of my SimulationWindow to the Server constructor like they do here:  [Modifying JavaFX gui from different thread in different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850217/modifying-javafx-gui-from-different-thread-in-different-class)

But Java wont let pass my SimulationWindow instance as parameter for the Server construtor.
Other solutions have the hold Server and SimulationWindow class as one but i want to keep them separated.
Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: In Server, add a constructor that takes the textArea as parameter

Comment: *"But Java wont let pass my SimulationWindow instance as parameter for the Server construtor."* What `SimulationWindow` instance: there isn't one in your code. Does `displaySimulationWindow()` really need to be `static`?

Comment: hi @James_D i added the instance method to the question. thanks for pointing that out. i removed static and now i can send the instance to the server constructor but still i cant access the serverTextArea from within the Server.

Comment: how do you expect a class to access a method local member of another class? snippets are rather useless, as you see ;)

Comment: hi @kleopatra thanks for the tip, im trying passing a TextArea as you suggested. Yes i need to learn to be careful with snippets. :P

Comment: I see `serverTextArea` is local variable ,how can `Server` class know this field ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this as kleopatra suggested. I passed a TextArea to my Server constructor. I wanted to update my TextArea in my GUI from my GUI Class and when getting messages from a client in the Server class. (I create and start my Server inside SimuWindow() )

```
public class myGUI{
    public void SimuWindow(){
        //this method creates all the GUI.
        Server myServer = new Server(serverTextArea);
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(myServer);
        serverThread.start();

        sendingTest = new TextField();
        sendingTest.setPromptText("test communication here");
        sendingTest.setOnAction(event -> {
        String message = new String ("\nServer says: ");
        message = message + sendingTest.getText();
        serverTextArea.appendText(message);
        myServer.sendMessage(message);
        sendingTest.clear();
    });
    }
}

public class Server implements Runnable{
    //This is my server class that connects and listens to clients
    TextArea mytextArea;
    public Server(TextArea x) {
        this.mytextArea = x;
    }
    private void whileConnected() throws IOException {          
    do {
        try {
            message = (String) input.readObject();  
            showMessage(message);               
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
            System.out.println("\n i dont know the message");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("Disconnected"));    

    private void showMessage(String mess) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> mytextArea.appendText(mess));           
    }
}
```

I did the same on my Client Class. Thanks for your help.